# htaccess and $_GET

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f        
RewriteRule ^articles(/\w+)$ ./search_page.php?mode=full_article&id=$1
```

the matter is to redirect all incoming urls like:
articles/XX
into:

```
search_page.php?mode=full_article&id=XX
```

the problem is that I get the "XX" with a "\".. that says, I get my id like this:
id=\XX
not
id=XX
why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You match everything after `articles` so the slash is included in your id. When you use `articles/` it doesn't include the slash because you match everything after it:

```
RewriteRule ^articles\/(\w+)$ ./search_page.php?mode=full_article&id=$1
```

So your sulition matches like this: `articlesYOURID` (www.youdomain.tld/articlesYOURID)

Now it matches this way: `articles/YOURID` (www.youdomain.tld/articles/YOURID)